# Numerically solve a gamma parameter estimation

Tags: matlab, numerical

I am trying to numerically solve an equation using fzero in Matlab. It is part of a bigger exercise. I haven't posted much here so not sure how much background information you need about this exercise so will try to keep it short.

This is my code:

```
fun = @(a)log(a/xBar) + (1/n) * log(dataProd) + diff(gamma(a))/gamma(a);
x0 = 0.8014;
x = fzero(fun,x0)
```

These are the values:
n = 209
xBar is 0.6078
dataProd = 3.1554e-77

I get the following error message in Matlab:

> Operands to the || and && operators must be convertible to logical
>   scalar values.
>
> Error in fzero (line 306)
>
> elseif ~isfinite(fx) || ~isreal(fx)

Any idea why I get this error message?

Comment: what is `diff` to you? Because `diff` computes differences between adjacent values in an array. The difference between values in a 1 value array is "inexistent" or `[]`, so `diff(gamma(a))` is `[]`. That makes `fun(a)` return `[]` when `a` is a single value, this `fzero` fails. Actually your `fun` is only defined for single values, so it always returns `[]`

Comment: If what you meant by the `diff` is a derivative of the gamma function then have a look at the Matlab function `psi`. You can use it to compute derivatives of Gamma. But since we don't know what you are trying to do, this is only a guess.

Comment: I was looking at this page: https://se.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/differentiation.html. That is why I thought diff was the differentiation of a function. So what I want is the derivative of gamma at point a divided by gamma. I seems like this is what psi(a) is. I changed diff(gamma(a))/gamma(a) to psi(a). Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that, during the search for a solution, fzero tries to evaluate your function at a=0, leading to an infinity. To check if this is the case, either look and see if you can set the optimization parameter 'display' to 'iter', or something similar in your version of Matlab. Otherwise, you can simply move your function to a separate m-file and call disp(a) on the first line. That way you will be able to see what fzero is doing and which value of a is causing the problem.